# NextJS Tailwind - Plain CSS Animation not working

Tags: css, next.js, css-animations, tailwind-css

I'm trying to get an animation working that I found here: https://codepen.io/goodkatz/pen/LYPGxQz.

I moved some of the animation code to tailwind for the React Component and left some code as plain css. When I run the component in Storybook it works like a charm, but when I run it with next dev, the animation doesn't work, it doesn't move whatsoever.

Here is the component:

```
import React from "react";
import "../../styles/WavesBackground.module.css";

export interface WavesBackgroundProps extends React.PropsWithChildren {}

export const WavesBackground: React.FC<WavesBackgroundProps> = () => {
  return (
    <div className="relative text-center bg-gradient-to-t from-lightgreen to-darkgreen m-0 p-0 w-full h-4/6">
      <div>
        <div className="m-0 p-0 w-full h-4/6 flex justify-center items-center text-center">
          <h1 className="font-light tracking-wide text-5xl h-24"></h1>
        </div>
        <svg
          className="waves relative w-full h-1/3 max-h-96 min-h-150px"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 24 150 28"
          preserveAspectRatio="none"
          shapeRendering="auto"
        >
          <defs>
            <path
              id="gentle-wave"
              d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z"
            />
          </defs>
          <g className="parallax">
            <use
              xlinkHref="#gentle-wave"
              x="48"
              y="0"
              fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.7"
            />
            <use
              xlinkHref="#gentle-wave"
              x="48"
              y="3"
              fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)"
            />
            <use
              xlinkHref="#gentle-wave"
              x="48"
              y="5"
              fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"
            />
            <use xlinkHref="#gentle-wave" x="48" y="7" fill="#fff" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here is the plain CSS file:

```
.waves {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  margin-bottom: -7px; /*Fix for safari gap*/
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 150px;
}

/* Animation */
.parallax > use {
  animation: move-forever 25s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.5, 0.45, 0.5) infinite;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-duration: 7s;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -3s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
  animation-duration: 13s;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
  animation-duration: 20s;
}
@keyframes move-forever {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(85px, 0, 0);
  }
}
/*Shrinking for mobile*/
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .waves {
    height: 40px;
    min-height: 40px;
  }
  .content {
    height: 30vh;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way to fix it, but it got fixed by moving the css out of a module.css file and into the globa.css file.